# $document.ready not triggering - Hosted on BlueHost

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently having trouble with a web application I am building for captive portal. I have all PHP and HTML parts of this application functioning. I have tried multiple function outside of the IF statement to check and see if the jQuery was running at all but it appears to be non functional.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(<?php echo $_POST['submit'];?> = Continue){
            $("#form1").hide(3s);
            $("#form2").show(3s);

        };
        alert('Hello world');
    });

</script>
```

As you can see the script is supposed to hide the first form, and show a second after the first form has run (it submits the information to the same page) by checking to see if submit has been posted. I apologize if this ends up being a very specific issue but I have spent the last 3 days and about 14 hours attempting to solve this issue, and have frankly run out of options.

Comment: Shoudln’t that be `if(<?php echo $_POST['submit'];?> == Continue)` with a `==` instead of `=`? Where’s `Continue` even declared?

Comment: Unless you have miscopied, the problem is definitely the line with the php echo ... should be this:

    if('<?php echo $_POST['submit'];?>' === 'Continue'){

Comment: you are showing `Continue` to be a javascript variable. Look in your browser console at errors thrown. The console is first place to get clues from

Comment: `3s` is what? that is not valid JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>    

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = '<?php echo "continue"; ?>';
if(x== "Continue"){
        $("#form1").hide(3000);
        $("#form2").show(3000);

    }
else
{
    alert();
}
    alert(x);
});
</script>
```

**Hope it helps you out.**

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are trying to compare 2 strings, so you must do:

```
if("<?php echo $_POST['submit'];?>" === "Continue") {...
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that. Unfortunately even with that change though it still won't run any of the commands either in or outside of the if statement.